# Safe to play with random strangers in D3 seasons on console?

Tags: diablo-iii

It's a *"well know fact"* that if you join random games in Diablo 3 on console you will invariably hit upon people with modded gear.

However, I do not know where this gear comes from. For instance, I've heard that the gear comes from modded Xbox 360 game saves.

Seasons was introduced to Diablo 3 on consoles this friday and with it comes a fresh start. As in, no existing gear, no existing paragon points, no nothing. You start fresh.

So my question is simple, but perhaps not easy to answer:

> Is it safe to join random strangers in a season when playing D3 on console? (in my specific case this would be Xbox One).

If the **only** source for modded gear is Xbox 360 hacked savedgames, then seasonal play would seem safe to me. If, on the other hand, it is possible to **also** hack Xbox One savegames, then I'm not so sure. I know the PC version of D3 runs the entire thing on servers, which makes it fairly impossible to hack anything but console D3 has never (to my knowledge) required this.

So I guess my question is really this: With seasons in D3 on Xbox One, is it possible to hack savegames to introduce +(whatever)%XP? Or is this thing a moot point now?

---

**Please note one thing**: I am not asking for your or anyone elses *opinion*. I am asking if anyone **knows** this. I have asked this question on facebook, on twitter, and a few other places and opinions are cheap. Facts are not. So if you *think* that it is safe, or that it isn't safe, that's really not an answer to this question. Whether you agree with this problem being something that needs to be solved/answered is not an answer either. I know that I don't *have* to spend all those 10k paragon points, but the fact that I *have* those points means I will be treated like an outcast.

Basically I am asking is if Blizzard solved the problem with modded gear for seasonal play.

---

So let me clarify what I asking about here.

I experienced back when Diablo 3 started on Xbox one that I joined a game with 3 others in it, and within seconds of me joining I had 10k paragon points. They had a xp boost item that gave them billions and trillions of XP during combat and some XP is shared when playing together. As such my paragon skyrocketed before I could react and before I could even leave the main town.

This too happened not because *I* had such a modded item, but because I joined a party where people had this type of item equipped.

So, in Diablo 3 on console and in seasons, as was recently released, I assume that there may be two ways for any player to get hold of such a modded item.

1. There is a way to hack current savegames and introduce new modded items on Xbox One
2. The source of all such modded items are the older Xbox 360 and basically a savegame that has been migrated to the new platform, which you can (could?)

If the latter, then any such items a person might have would be locked outside the season, but if there is still a way to hack savegames, then this may still be a problem even in seasons on consoles.

If the only source of these items was from old hacked 360 games, then these would not be possible to bring into a seasonable character and thus be safe.

Comment: What do you mean "safe"? Another player's gear has no effect on you at all, there is no risk involved in joining a game with a player with modded gear, seasonal or otherwise. I don't know if Blizzard has found a way to ensure fairness on console D3 yet, but I fail to understand what possible risk you might be talking about.

Comment: I can attest that there is no way to "legally" trade items in Seasonal play, as you cannot see party member's dropped items, and you cannot use the mailbox. With this in place, you will never accidentally pick up or equip modded gear, if you run into anyone using it (if that's something you worry about).

Comment: The assumption that other players gear doesn't impact you is incorrect. People have applied modded xp gems on items which impact the amount of xp the entire group gets, which means that if I join such a game with a player with such an item, and he's in combat, my xp will be boosted even though I am still in town. You don't have to trade or get the item yourself. As such, my question seem to still stand.

Comment: See http://www.diablofans.com/forums/diablo-iii-general-forums/diablo-iii-general-discussion/142310-hacked-console-item as an example, if a player runs around with this kind of item, he will impact others in his group as well. That is, whether this item is enough or he must have other items to share that xp I don't know but I have had one character on Xbox One ruined by this at the very start. Since everybody I tried to play with regarded me as pestilence when I joined with 10k paragon I had to delete the savegame and restart.

Comment: Not definitive so I won't put it as an answer, but there's really no such thing as unhackable local storage.  If the game can access and modify the data, so can a sufficiently motivated hacker.  I'd vote "unsafe".  Maybe make a suggestion to Blizzard to add a "don't accept shared exp" option for consoles?  It seems like that would be pretty trivial to add, maybe they'll surprise you in a patch or two.